elasticsearch regex split into groups 255 characters
First of all, sorry for my English. I have encountered the following issue when performing a query with regular expressions in Elasticsearch.
This index field is a text longer than 255 characters (This is important).
Field search for
When performing the following search, it does not return it as a result, which I found strange.
Regexp Query
So, I performed this other search and while it did return a result, I found it odd how Elasticsearch highlighted it.
Try 2
Result
When I checked the length of the highlighted text, I found it to be 255 characters.
To confirm a theory I had in mind, I performed a third search and it found it.
Try 3
Elasticsearch highlighted this other portion of the entire text.
Result
This led me to develop a theory that when performing the search by regular expression, Elasticsearch was separating the entire text of the field into portions of 255 characters and performing the search within each portion separately.
Perhaps I am stating something that is obvious to you, but I need help finding a solution so that the regular expression performs an integral search across the entire content of the field.

Could you repost the code snippets as code by surrounding them with 3 backticks - ``` on the first line and the same on the last or using any other methods described here - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code Posting code as images makes life of the people who want to reproduce your problem difficult and may even frustrate some people. As you can see somebody already voted to close your question as lacking clarity. Another way to improve clarity would be to post the mapping for that field.
